# oone exmple in hash topics?

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, probability-theory, hash, hashing

Example: Suppose $H:${$1,...,n$} $\rightarrow ${$1,..,n$} be a uniform hash function. for input $x$, $z$ is equal to number of trailing zero in the right side of $H(x)$. for $0 \leq c \leq 1$ what is the order of probability $ z \geq c \log n$? $C$ is constant here.

Answer: $O(1/n^c)$

How  this this is can be achieved?

I think this is same with this question:

Source: introduction to algorithm [CLRS Page 652 Ex.11-C](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0262033844)
[image]

Comment: Please credit the source of where you saw this question, and the source of all copied material.

Comment: What have you tried?  What progress have you made so far?  Where did you get stuck?  We discourage posts that simply state a problem out of context, and expect the community to solve it.  We do not want to just do your exercise for you; we want you to gain understanding. However, as it is we do not know what your underlying problem is, so it's hard to know how to begin to help. Assuming you tried to solve it yourself and got stuck, it may be helpful if you wrote your thoughts and what you could not figure out.  (If not, you should spend some time thinking about the problem before asking.)

Answer (score 2):

Let $A_n\subseteq \{0,1\}^{\log n}$ denote the set of binary strings of length $\log n$ with at least $c\log n$ trailing zeros on the right (here I assume that $\log n$ in an integer and $0\le c\le 1$). Note that $|A_n|=2^{\log n -\lceil c\log n\rceil}\le 2^{(1-c)\log n}$. Since $H:\{0,1\}^{\log n}\rightarrow \{0,1\}^{\log n}$ is a one to one function, $\Pr_{x\sim U_{\log n}}\left[H(x)\in A_n\right]=\frac{|A_n|}{2^{\log n}}\le\frac{1}{n^c}$, where $U_k$ is the uniform distribution over $\{0,1\}^k$.

Comment: This is basically just counting, half the strings are mapped to strings with at least one zero on the right, $\frac{1}{4}$ to strings with $\ge 2 $ zeros and $2^{-k}$ to strings with $\ge k$ zeros. The question from CLRS is only loosely related (one has to have a solid grasp of the assumptions involved, e.g. that all $m!$ probing permutations are equally likely for a uniformly distributed input). Under such assumptions, since at least half of the table is always empty, the probability of having to go through more than $k$ cells is $\le 2^k$.

Comment: The key observation is that since $H$ is a correspondence, $Pr_x[H(x)\in A]$ is just $\frac{|A|}{n}$.

Comment: There's nothing serious going on, I suggest that you take your time with the information at hand and try to make up the answer yourself.

Comment: what's the question means?